# Mapping by code on Class that has a property of type ICollection<>

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to map a class that has a property of type `ICollection<>` using NHibernate mapping by code. The code below works. But I don't like the extra `Person` property within `CarSet` to make the mapping work.

```
 public class PersonSet
    {        
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CarSet> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarSet
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual PersonSet Person { get; set; }
    }


    public class PersonSetMap : ClassMapping<PersonSet>
    {
        public PersonSetMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m=>m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x=>x.Name);
            Set(x => x.Cars, c =>
                {
                    c.Key(k =>
                        {
                            k.Column("PersonId");
                        });
                     c.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
                    c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                }, r =>
                    {
                        r.OneToMany();
                    }
                );
        }
    }

    public class CarSetMap : ClassMapping<CarSet>
    {
        public CarSetMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x => x.Name);
            ManyToOne(x => x.Person, m =>
            {
                m.Column("PersonId");
                m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

        }
    }

      public void Save(){

       using (var session = Cfg.Session)
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
               PersonSet John = new PersonSet { Name = PersonName.John };
               John.Cars = new List<CarSet> { 
                new CarSet { Name = CarnName.BMW,Person = John},
                  new CarSet { Name = CarnName.BM,Person = John }};
                session.Save(entity);
                tx.Commit();
            }

    }
```

The code above generates SQL script below:

```
  create table PersonSet (
      Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
     Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
     primary key (Id)
  )

  create table CarSet (
      Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
     Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
     PersonId INT not null,
     primary key (id)
  )

  alter table CarSet
      add constraint FKF967D6489A220265
      foreign key (PersonId)
      references PersonSet
```

What I want is to generate SQL script with difference shown below, and keep the rest the same:

```
 create table CarSet (     
     Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
     PersonId INT not null,

  )
```

Ideally I want the `CarSet` like this instead:

```
public class CarSet
{
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

map Cars as ComponentCollection

```
class Person
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.Name);
        Set(x => x.Cars, c =>
        {
            c.Key(k => k.Column("PersonId"));
            c.Cascade(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Cascade.Persist);
            c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
        }, r =>
        {
            r.Component(c =>
            {
                c.Parent(x => x.Owner);
                c.Property(x => x.Name);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. NHibernate requires all columns of component collection sets to be not-null. Reference: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-incollections

Comment: not exactly true. Only for `Set` mapping all columns have to be not-null. And i missed it in the requirements that the Name should be nullable. Switch to Bag or List if nullable is required

Answer (score 0):

Your ideal solution isn't possible. To use a CarSet table without it's own ID column it has to be a component, but component sets can't have nullable columns. If it's ok for you to mark `Name` as not-null you can adapt the solution Firo posted.

If that's not ok you can at least solve your first request to remove the `Person` property. Just delete the property and mark the key column in your set mapping as not-nullable. `CarSet` will still be an entity (and therefore have it's own ID) but you don't need the reference to `PersonSet` in code.

Btw, why are your classes postfixed by `Set`? Just naming them `Person` and `Car` would be much better since they only represent one person or car, not a collection of them.